# Index a BAM file using pysam

Tags: sam, indexing

(How) can you index a BAM file using `pysam`?

When I tried the intuitive `pysam.index` I got:

```
import pysam
my_bam = pysam.AlignmentFile("regular_bwamem_mapping.bam", "rb")
pysam.index(my_bam)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-a0b3a04ecb2c> in <module>
----> 1 pysam.index(L_bam)

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pysam/utils.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     59             args,
     60             catch_stdout=kwargs.get("catch_stdout", True),
---> 61             save_stdout=kwargs.get("save_stdout", None))
     62
     63         if kwargs.get("split_lines", False):

pysam/libcutils.pyx in pysam.libcutils._pysam_dispatch()

TypeError: object of type 'pysam.libcalignmentfile.AlignmentFile' has no len()
```

Comment: disclaimer: when I post a question and answer, it's because I figure the answer while I write the question.

Comment: I have tried same command...
error
[E::hts_idx_push] Unsorted positions on sequence #8: 3411049 followed by 3378665
[E::sam_index] Read 'A00404:40:HFGYNDSXX:4:1258:24623:27633' with ref_name='chr8', ref_length=145138636, flags=1107, pos=3378665 cannot be indexed
Traceback (most recent call last): File "Insertx.py", line 283, in <module> main() File "Insertx.py", line 263, in main pysam.index(str(''.join( data))) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pysam/utils.py", line 69, in __call__ raise SamtoolsError(
pysam.utils.SamtoolsError: 'samtools returned with error 1: stdout=, stderr=samt

Comment: @anju there must have been something that gone wrong with sorting the file. Otherwise it would not complain about it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Oh you silly sausage, `pysam.index` takes a bam file name, not a python object.

```
import pysam
pysam.index("regular_bwamem_mapping.bam")
```

will index your `.bam` file.

Comment: I should print "Oh you silly sausage" and tape it above my monitor.